# How to check for empty json response with regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, json

My ajax response returns an empty response (ie with multiple lines of blank spaces) and i want to check that in my success function. How to check for empty json response with regex in javascript?

Comment: Can you give an example of such a response? Does it contain properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> /^\s*$/.test("foo")
false
> /^\s*$/.test("")
true
> /^\s*$/.test("   ")
true
> /^\s*$/.test("\n\n")
true
```

Comment: +1 especially for using `regex.test` instead of `string.match`.

Answer (score -1):

1. Set `jQuery.ajax` datatype to `text`
2. Create the following `success` callback

   ```
   $.ajax({
     // other options..
     dataType: 'text',
     success(planinTextData) {
       if (planinTextData !== '') {
         var data = JSON.parse(planinTextData);
       }
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: -1 The OP specifically mentioned _"multiple lines of blank spaces"_ which this misses. (P.S. Eight spaces of indent for code inside a list item.)